# Get PDF page from SWF Offer Avis

Tags: c#, pdf, flash

If you click on http://www.foetex.dk/ugenstilbud/Pages/Zmags.aspx you can see there's a PDF logo, so you can download the offer Avis for the week. I want to download that automatic, but i can't think of a way to do that, aslong as their site is in flash.

Please come with tips and tricks

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        WebClient wb = new WebClient();
        var data = new NameValueCollection();
        data["publicationID"] = "6dce3366"; //Netto ID
        data["selectedPages"] = "all";


        byte[] responsebytes = wb.UploadValues("http://viewer.zmags.com/services/DownloadPDF", "POST", data);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Tilbudsavis.pdf", responsebytes);
```

This was the answer.